# Trying to group a query to display day event by hours

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get an account of a daily count from an Oracle query to display count by hours from 14:00 to 19:00. I'm using this query. I want to group the count output.

```
Select count(*), extract(hour from eventtime) as hours
from   TR_MFS_LOADCARRIER
WHERE  eventid = 5
And    eventtime BETWEEN to_date('05/09/2022 14:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                     and to_date('05/09/2022 19:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
group by hours
```

It fails where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hours` alias is defined in the `SELECT` clause after the `GROUP BY` clause is evaluated so it cannot be used in the `GROUP BY` clause; use `EXTRACT(hour from eventtime)` instead.

```sql
Select count(*),
       extract(hour from eventtime) as hours
from   TR_MFS_LOADCARRIER
WHERE  eventid = 5
And    eventtime BETWEEN to_date('05/09/2022 14:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                     and to_date('05/09/2022 19:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
group by extract(hour from eventtime)
```

If your `eventtime` column is a `DATE` data-type then you cannot `EXTRACT` the hours field and need to cast it to a `TIMESTAMP` data-type:

```sql
Select count(*),
       extract(hour from CAST(eventtime AS TIMESTAMP)) as hours
from   TR_MFS_LOADCARRIER
WHERE  eventid = 5
And    eventtime BETWEEN to_date('05/09/2022 14:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                     and to_date('05/09/2022 19:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
group by extract(hour from CAST(eventtime AS TIMESTAMP))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F7GRVWTA)

Comment: Thats great but how do  I display hours 1pm, 2pm 3pm etc as a grouo statement with the count recors

Comment: @user616076 Please can you clarify the question as "as a grouo statement with the count recors" is not clear.

Comment: I want a group statement to display the count for every hour from 13:00 to 18:00. At the moent it returns one count I want evry hours count

Comment: @user616076 The query in the answer does exactly that; you can look at the linked fiddle to see it outputting counts for each hour. If your query only outputs a single value then you only have data for one hour.

Comment: Both only out put to one line, I need a group for each hour. If I'm doing this wrong please show an example where it works

Comment: @user616076 Have you clicked the fiddle link in the question? It works there.

Comment: I have but when I run it in TOAD I only get one line, why is that?

Comment: @user616076 Please create [MRE] in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7Jxju0AY) that replicates the problem by recreating your table and data and then I may be able to tell you why. If you cannot replicate it then I won't be able to help as I cannot see your data or what you are doing in toad.